# INSERT INTO INNER JOIN in Visual Basic

Tags: mysql, vb.net, vb.net-2010

I used INSERT INTO INNER JOIN statement because I need some data from table1 to be inserted also in my table2. But I'm getting an error of `"OLEDbExceptionUnhandled: Missing semicolon (;) at end of SQL statement."` But I can't figure out where this semicolon should be. Hope someone can help me.

The ff is my code:

```
Dim cmd As OleDbCommand = New OleDbCommand("INSERT INTO Table1
(Check_No,Voucher_No,Issue_Date,Company_Name,Bank_Type, 
Amount_in_Figure,Amount_in_Words,Payee,Particulars,Remarks) 
VALUES('" & Me.txtCheckNo.Text & "','" & Me.txtVoucherNo.Text & "', '" & 
Me.dtpDate.Text & "', '" & Me.txtCompName.Text & "', '" & 
Me.txtBankType.Text & "','" & Me.txtAmtInFigure.Text & "','" & 
Me.txtAmtInWords.Text & "','" & Me.txtPayTo.Text & "','" & 
Me.txtParticulars.Text & "','" & Me.cmbRemarks.SelectedItem & "') 
SELECT ID,Check_No,Voucher_No 
FROM Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 AS vNo ON Table1.Check_No = vNo.Check_Number, 
Table1.Voucher_No = vNo.Voucher_Number, Table1.ID = vNo.CompanyID", 
myConnection)

myConnection.Open()
cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
myConnection.Close()
```

Comment: AFAIK the semicolon should be at the end of the statement, e.g. `Table1.ID = vNo.CompanyID;`

Comment: I tried putting the semicolon there but when I run the program, same error appears. @TimBiegeleisen

Comment: The first sql statement (the INSERT) ends just before the SELECT and here goes is the _missing semicolon_ Hower your code will never work as you seem to expect. The second statement (SELECT) is in no way connected to the first one. It will never inserts two fields from the second table in the first table

Comment: After that, read how to write a parameterized query. Your code is a book recipe for errors and for sql injection

Comment: Aww okay. Can you tell me what to do to make it work? @Steve And yea, better read about that. Thank you.

Comment: It is not a capital sin to write two different INSERT statements loading the data required before writing it back in the required table. It could be a problem only if performances are of uttermost importance here

Comment: If that so, how can I have a foreign key in my second table if I'll use two different INSERT statements? I mean how can I get the last inserted id from the first table and insert it at the same time as foreign key on the second table? @Steve

Comment: @Erica see my answer below

Answer (score 0):

> But I can't figure out where this semicolon should be.

before this line:

```
SELECT ID,Check_No,Voucher_No
```